# Triple DES decryption in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption

I'm currently using the following for Triple DES decryption on iOS:

```
    NSString* plainText = @"My Text";
    NSString* keyText = @"cf6f1ed3bf0a156e";

    NSData *plainData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [keyText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t bufferSize = plainData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES;
    NSMutableData *cypherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSize];
    size_t movedBytes = 0;

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
            kCCAlgorithm3DES,
            kCCOptionECBMode,
            keyData.bytes,
            kCCBlockSize3DES,
            NULL,
            plainData.bytes,
            plainData.length,
            cypherData.mutableBytes,
            cypherData.length,
            &movedBytes);

    cypherData.length = movedBytes;

    if( ccStatus == kCCSuccess ) {
        NSLog(@"Data: %@",cypherData);
        NSLog(@"Data encoded string: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cypherData bytes]]);
        NSLog(@"Data encoded: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:cypherData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed DES decrypt ...");
        return nil;
    }
```

However, I keep getting the following in the console:

> Data:  
>   Data encoded string:(null)
>   Data encoded: (null)

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Can anyone see any possible issues with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the failure message to:

```
NSLog(@"Failed DES decrypt, status: %d", ccStatus);
```

You will see a `-4300` status and look that up in `CommonCryptoError.h` to find:
`kCCParamError = -4300`
`@constant kCCParamError Illegal parameter value.`

Status errors can be your friend if you don't ignore them.

1. You are specifying 3DES which should have a key length of 24-bytes, you are supplying 16-bytes. You are probably better off changing to `kCCAlgorithmDES` and `kCCBlockSizeDES` (see next point). But the key may be hex encoded and needs to be decoded to 8-bytes.
2. In the call the 5th parameter is `size_t keyLength` but you are supplying `kCCBlockSize3DES` which is 8-bytes. Key and block size are not necessarily the same size.
3. No padding is the default and that means that the data to be encrypted **must** be an **exact** multiple of the block size (8-bytes). Either add another byte to the input data or specify `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` as an option.
4. In general it is not possible to express the result of encryption directly in a character string, particularly not a UTF-8 representation—there are byte values that are not displayable. For this reason if you need a character string encoding either Base64 or hexadecimal are generally used.

Note: There is a possibility the key is 16-bytes and two-key 3DES is needed, in that case duplicate and append the first 8-bytes to the key to make is a 24-byte 3DES key. You need to come to grips with the algorithm, key and options.

This example code works but is neither optimal nor secure but a starting point to get you going:

You can change this to 3DES by supplying a 24-byte key and changing `kCCAlgorithmDES` to `kCCAlgorithm3DES` and `kCCKeySizeDES` to `kCCKeySize3DES`

```
NSString* plainText = @"My Text-";
NSString* keyText = @"cf6f1ed3";

NSData *plainData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *keyData = [keyText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t bufferSize = plainData.length + kCCBlockSizeDES;
NSMutableData *cypherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSize];
size_t movedBytes = 0;

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmDES,
                   kCCOptionECBMode,
                   keyData.bytes,
                   kCCKeySizeDES,
                   NULL,
                   plainData.bytes,
                   plainData.length,
                   cypherData.mutableBytes,
                   cypherData.length,
                   &movedBytes);

cypherData.length = movedBytes;

if( ccStatus == kCCSuccess ) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@"encoded,cypherData);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed DES decrypt, status: %d", ccStatus);
}
```

But for security reasons use AES with a random IV, if possible use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc), it will take care of all the nasty but important details for you.

Comment: would have never thought of the keys being an issue. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Your key is 16 bytes long. 3DES takes a key that is 24 bytes long (thanks Zaph for correcting; also noting you're only reading 8 bytes of that). This may not be causing this error, but means the key isn't what you think it is.

A series of hex digits in a string are just UTF-8 values. "00" is not 0x00, 0x00. It's 0x30, 0x30.

The reason you're getting `(null)` here is this:

```
NSLog(@"Data encoded string: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cypherData bytes]]);
```

Cryptographic output is very unlikely to be a legal UTF-8 string. If you want to encode random data as a string, you need an encoding like hex encoding or Base64 encoding. Base64 is built in and you can use `[NSData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]` to encode it.